# Laravel query not getting correct results

Tags: laravel

When a user types keywords for the search filter, I want to query tags related to posts. If the keyword is "water body" the result of the filter should return posts that have both tags (water and body). My code below shows results that has either of the tags

How do I query to get only collections that contain both tags?

```
public function searchFilter(Request $request, Post $post){
        $terms = explode(" ", $request->input('keyword'));
        $posts =  $post->newQuery();
        $page = (int)$request->input('page', 1);
        $perPage = (int)$request->input('perPage', 10);
        $keyword = $request->keyword;

        if($request->has('keyword')){

            $posts->where(function($query) use($keyword) {
                    $query->Where('name','LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                    ->orWhereHas('super', function($q) use ($keyword)
                    {
                        $q->where('name','LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
                    })
                    ->orWhereHas('tags', function($q) use ($keyword)
                    {
                        $q->where('name','LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
                    });
                });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explode your keywords and then add orWhereHas for each keyword:

`````
//...
$keywords = explode(' ', $request->keyword);

//...

// Then in your query, use foreach to search for each keyword (do the same for each field
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    $query->orWhereHas('tags', function($q) use ($keyword) {
        $q->where('name','LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
    });
}
````
`````